# Having file encoding is making env selection obsolete in karate

Tags: karate

Having file encoding -

```
<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
```

makes the kaate env as null

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e".
```

I think there is a bug here. Tried all versions from 0.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

`-DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

Comment: I will try this. Thanks!